# Error after adding ERC2771Context and MinimalForwarder to smart contract to support meta-transactions

Tags: solidity, openzeppelin, meta-transactions, erc2771

I am getting this error after adding `ERC2771Context` and `MinimalForwarder` from `open-zeppelin` to my smart contract:

```
TypeError: Immutable variables cannot be read before they are initialized.
  --> @openzeppelin/contracts/metatx/ERC2771Context.sol:21:29:
   |
21 |         return forwarder == _trustedForwarder;
   |                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^


Error HH600: Compilation failed
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was that I was inheriting `Ownable` before `ERC2771Context`. As `Ownable` uses `Context` and `Context` defines `_msgSender()`, you must inherit `ERC2771Context` BEFORE `Ownable` in your smart contracts.

Answer (score 1):

Did you set the address of the minimalforwarder as a constructor parameter in your contract's deploy script? If not please pass the address of the minimal forwarder contract as a constructor argument in your deploy script.

If you want more reference on MetaTransactions check out my ERC20MetaTx Employee registry code: https://github.com/praveen-agiratech/AgiraMetaTx
it has easy to follow readme guide

Video tutorial I followed: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bhz5LJbq9YY

I hope these will give you an idea about how to use MetaTx in your contracts.